# How do I add a 2D sprite animation to a cocos3D scene?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I have an app with a cocos3d scene in which I have a 3D animated model. I want to add some effects to the scene and I was thinking of using planes textured with a sprite animation.

I've been able to add the full sprite image to the scene correctly, but this isn't obviously what I want to do.

```
CC3PlaneNode *sprite = [CC3PlaneNode nodeWithName:@"Sprite"];
[sprite populateAsRectangleWithSize:CGSizeMake(10, 10) andRelativeOrigin:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
sprite.location = cc3v(-0.5, -1, -5);

CCTexture* tex2D = [CCTextureCache.sharedTextureCache  addImage:@"equalizer.png"];
CC3Texture* tex3D = [CC3Texture textureWithCCTexture: tex2D];
tex3D.name = @"EqualizerTextureFile";
[CC3Texture addTexture: tex3D];
sprite.texture = tex3D;
[self addChild:sprite];
```

I've noticed there is a **CCSprite** class that seems to be related to what I want to do, but it is incredibly hard to figure out how to use it, mainly since I have a cocos3D scene not a cocos2D one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed a 2D *Cocos2D* node (including a `CCSprite`) in a 3D **Cocos3D** scene, by using a `CC3Billboard`.

`CC3Billboard` is a 3D **Cocos3D** node that can hold a 2D *Cocos2D* node.

The `CC3DemoMashUp` demo app in the **Cocos3D** distribution contains several examples of using a `CC3Billboard` to embed a 2D node (even a 2D particle system) in a 3D scene.

Comment: Thank you Bill for the answer, and thank you for developing Cocos!